# Touch event not working

Tags: android, touch

I am implementing a game which is having touch events and I have implemented that but not working. Here is my code for touch listener:

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    int action = event.getAction();
    if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
    {
        if(event.getX()> r.x && event.getX()< (r.x +100) && event.getY()>(r.y-20) && event.getY()<r.y)
        {
            touch = true;
        }
        return true;
    }
    else if(action == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE && touch)
    {
        if(event.getX()>0 && event.getX()<220)
        {
            r.x = event.getX();
            r.y = event.getY();
        }
        return true;

    }

    return false;

}
```

here r is the object of rectangle and x and y are the coordinates of rectangle.

Comment: did you check whether there is problem in your if-else logic OR your listener itself is not called. Please check by simply putting a log statement or either by debugging and may be then we can help you more on this.

Comment: @mudit:the listener is not calling at all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am writing the touch listener in surfaceview so i have written the listener in activity hence problwm solved